# Node.js http.request Express multiple requests with single res.render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async.js

I have successfully figured out node.js/Express code for making a single http.request to my server. However, the next step is to make multiple requests which use the same res.render statement at the end.

Here is my successful working code:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    // MODULES - INCLUDES
    var xml2js = require('xml2js');
    var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

    // FORM - SUBMIT - CUCMMAPPER
    app.post('/cucmmapper/submit', function (req, res) {

        // FORM - DATA COLLECTION
        var cucmpub = req.body.cucmpub;
        var cucmversion = req.body.cucmversion;
        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;

        // JS - VARIABLE DEFINITION
        var authentication = username + ":" + password;
        var soapreplyx = '';
        var cssx = '';
        var spacer = '-----';
        var rmline1 = '';
        var rmline2 = '';
        var rmline3 = '';
        var rmline4 = '';
        var rmbottomup1 = '';
        var rmbottomup2 = '';
        var rmbottomup3 = '';

        // HTTP.REQUEST - BUILD CALL
        var https = require("https");
        var headers = {
            'SoapAction': 'CUCM:DB ver=' + cucmversion + ' listCss',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(authentication).toString('base64'),
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        };

        // SOAP - AXL CALL
        var soapBody = new Buffer('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/11.5">' +
            '<soapenv:Header/>' +
            '<soapenv:Body>' +
            '<ns:listCss sequence="?">' +
            '<searchCriteria>' +
            '<name>%</name>' +
            '</searchCriteria>' +
            '<returnedTags uuid="?">' +
            '<name>?</name>' +
            '<description>?</description>' +
            '<clause>?</clause>' +
            '</returnedTags>' +
            '</ns:listCss>' +
            '</soapenv:Body>' +
            '</soapenv:Envelope>');

        // HTTP.REQUEST - OPTIONS
        var options = {
            host: cucmpub, // IP ADDRESS OF CUCM PUBLISHER
            port: 8443, // DEFAULT CISCO SSL PORT
            path: '/axl/', // AXL URL
            method: 'POST', // AXL REQUIREMENT OF POST
            headers: headers, // HEADER VAR
            rejectUnauthorized: false // REQUIRED TO ACCEPT SELF-SIGNED CERTS
        };

        // HTTP.REQUEST - Doesn't seem to need this line, but it might be useful anyway for pooling?
        options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

        // HTTP.REQUEST - OPEN SESSION
        let soapRequest = https.request(options, soapResponse => {
            soapResponse.setEncoding('utf8');
            soapResponse.on('data', chunk => {
                soapreplyx += chunk
            });
            // HTTP.REQUEST - RESULTS + RENDER
            soapResponse.on('end', () => {

                // EDIT - SCRUB XML OUTPUT
                var rmline1 = soapreplyx.replace(/<\?xml\sversion='1\.0'\sencoding='utf-8'\?>/g, '');
                var rmline2 = rmline1.replace(/<soapenv:Envelope\sxmlns:soapenv="http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/">/g, '');
                var rmline3 = rmline2.replace(/<soapenv:Body>/g, '');
                var rmline4 = rmline3.replace(/<ns:listCssResponse\sxmlns:ns="http:\/\/www\.cisco\.com\/AXL\/API\/[0-9]*\.[0-9]">/g, '');
                var rmbottomup1 = rmline4.replace(/<\/soapenv:Envelope>/g, '');
                var rmbottomup2 = rmbottomup1.replace(/<\/soapenv:Body>/g, '');
                var xmlscrubbed = rmbottomup2.replace(/<\/ns:listCssResponse>/g, '');
                // console.log(xmlscrubbed);
                // console.log(spacer);

                // XML2JS - TESTING
                parser.parseString(xmlscrubbed, function (err, result) {
                    var cssx = result['return']['css'];
                    //   console.log(cssx);
                    //   console.log(spacer);
                    res.render('cucmmapper-results.html', {
                        title: 'CUCM Toolbox',
                        cucmpub: cucmpub,
                        cssx: cssx,
                        soapreply: soapreplyx,
                        xmlscrubbed: xmlscrubbed
                    });
                });
            });
        });

        // SOAP - SEND AXL CALL
        soapRequest.write(soapBody);
        soapRequest.end();
    });
}
```

My guess is that I have to setup several things to make this work:

- Another "var soapBody" with my new request (I can do this).
- Another "let soapRequest" (I'm good with this too).
- Another "soapRequest.write" statement (Again, easy enough).
- Split the "res.render" statement out of the specific "let soapRequest" statement and gather all the variable (this is where I'm stuck).

My guess is that I need to use [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html). However, I can't for the life of me wrap my head around how to get that "res.render" to work with async.

Here is the closest I can come to an answer. However, the "cssx" and "partitionsx" variable are not translated over to the "function complete". They both still show up as null.

```
module.exports = function (app) {

    // MODULES - INCLUDES
    var xml2js = require('xml2js');
    var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

    // FORM - SUBMIT - CUCMMAPPER
    app.post('/cucmmapper/submit', function (req, res) {

        // FORM - DATA COLLECTION
        var cucmpub = req.body.cucmpub;
        var cucmversion = req.body.cucmversion;
        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;

        // JS - VARIABLE DEFINITION - GLOBAL
        var authentication = username + ":" + password;
        var soapreplyx = '';
        var cssx = null;
        var spacer = '-----';
        var rmline1 = '';
        var rmline2 = '';
        var rmline3 = '';
        var rmline4 = '';
        var rmbottomup1 = '';
        var rmbottomup2 = '';
        var rmbottomup3 = '';
        var soapreplyp = '';
        var partitionsx = null;
        var rmline1p = '';
        var rmline2p = '';
        var rmline3p = '';
        var rmline4p = '';
        var rmbottomup1p = '';
        var rmbottomup2p = '';
        var rmbottomup3p = '';

        // HTTP.REQUEST - BUILD CALL - GLOBAL
        var https = require("https");
        var headers = {
            'SoapAction': 'CUCM:DB ver=' + cucmversion + ' listCss',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(authentication).toString('base64'),
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        };

        // SOAP - AXL CALL - CSS
        var soapBody = new Buffer('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/11.5">' +
            '<soapenv:Header/>' +
            '<soapenv:Body>' +
            '<ns:listCss sequence="?">' +
            '<searchCriteria>' +
            '<name>%</name>' +
            '</searchCriteria>' +
            '<returnedTags uuid="?">' +
            '<name>?</name>' +
            '<description>?</description>' +
            '<clause>?</clause>' +
            '</returnedTags>' +
            '</ns:listCss>' +
            '</soapenv:Body>' +
            '</soapenv:Envelope>');

        // SOAP - AXL CALL - PARTITIONS
        var soapBody2 = new Buffer('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/11.5">' +
            '<soapenv:Header/>' +
            '<soapenv:Body>' +
            '<ns:listRpite{artotopm} sequence="?">' +
            '<searchCriteria>' +
            '<name>%</name>' +
            '</searchCriteria>' +
            '<returnedTags uuid="?">' +
            '<name>?</name>' +
            '</returnedTags>' +
            '</ns:listRoutePartition>' +
            '</soapenv:Body>' +
            '</soapenv:Envelope>');

        // HTTP.REQUEST - OPTIONS - GLOBAL
        var options = {
            host: cucmpub, // IP ADDRESS OF CUCM PUBLISHER
            port: 8443, // DEFAULT CISCO SSL PORT
            path: '/axl/', // AXL URL
            method: 'POST', // AXL REQUIREMENT OF POST
            headers: headers, // HEADER VAR
            rejectUnauthorized: false // REQUIRED TO ACCEPT SELF-SIGNED CERTS
        };

        // HTTP.REQUEST - GLOBAL (Doesn't seem to need this line, but it might be useful anyway for pooling?)
        options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

        // HTTP.REQUEST - OPEN SESSION - CSS
        var soapRequest = https.request(options, soapResponse => {
            soapResponse.setEncoding('utf8');
            soapResponse.on('data', chunk => {
                soapreplyx += chunk
            });
            // HTTP.REQUEST - RESULTS + RENDER
            soapResponse.on('end', () => {

                // EDIT - SCRUB XML OUTPUT
                var rmline1 = soapreplyx.replace(/<\?xml\sversion='1\.0'\sencoding='utf-8'\?>/g, '');
                var rmline2 = rmline1.replace(/<soapenv:Envelope\sxmlns:soapenv="http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/">/g, '');
                var rmline3 = rmline2.replace(/<soapenv:Body>/g, '');
                var rmline4 = rmline3.replace(/<ns:listCssResponse\sxmlns:ns="http:\/\/www\.cisco\.com\/AXL\/API\/[0-9]*\.[0-9]">/g, '');
                var rmbottomup1 = rmline4.replace(/<\/soapenv:Envelope>/g, '');
                var rmbottomup2 = rmbottomup1.replace(/<\/soapenv:Body>/g, '');
                var xmlscrubbed = rmbottomup2.replace(/<\/ns:listCssResponse>/g, '');
                // console.log(xmlscrubbed);
                // console.log(spacer);

                // XML2JS - TESTING
                parser.parseString(xmlscrubbed, function (err, result) {
                    var cssx = result['return']['css'];
                    //   console.log(cssx);
                    //   console.log(spacer);
                    complete();
                });
            });
        });

        // SOAP - SEND AXL CALL - CSS
        soapRequest.write(soapBody);
        soapRequest.end();

        // SOAP - SEND AXL CALL - PARTITIONS
        var soapRequest2 = https.request(options, soapResponse2 => {
            soapResponse2.setEncoding('utf8');
            soapResponse2.on('data', chunk => {
                soapreplyp += chunk
            });
            // HTTP.REQUEST - RESULTS + RENDER
            soapResponse2.on('end', () => {

                // EDIT - SCRUB XML OUTPUT
                var rmline1p = soapreplyy.replace(/<\?xml\sversion='1\.0'\sencoding='utf-8'\?>/g, '');
                var rmline2p = rmline1.replace(/<soapenv:Envelope\sxmlns:soapenv="http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/">/g, '');
                var rmline3p = rmline2.replace(/<soapenv:Body>/g, '');
                var rmline4p = rmline3.replace(/<ns:listCssResponse\sxmlns:ns="http:\/\/www\.cisco\.com\/AXL\/API\/[0-9]*\.[0-9]">/g, '');
                var rmbottomup1p = rmline4.replace(/<\/soapenv:Envelope>/g, '');
                var rmbottomup2p = rmbottomup1.replace(/<\/soapenv:Body>/g, '');
                var xmlscrubbedp = rmbottomup2.replace(/<\/ns:listCssResponse>/g, '');
                console.log(xmlscrubbedp);
                console.log(spacer);

                // XML2JS - TESTING
                parser.parseString(xmlscrubbedp, function (err, result) {
                    var partitionsx = result['return']['css'];
                    //   console.log(partitionsx);
                    //   console.log(spacer);
                    complete();
                });
            });
        });
        // SOAP - SEND AXL CALL - PARTITIONS
        soapRequest2.write(soapBody2);
        soapRequest2.end();

        // PAGE - RENDER
        function complete() {
            if (cssx !== null && partitionsx !== null) {
                res.render('cucmmapper-results.html', {
                    title: 'CUCM Toolbox',
                    cucmpub: cucmpub,
                    cssx: cssx,
                    partitionsx: partitionsx,
                })
            } else {
                res.render('cucmerror.html', {
                    title: 'CUCM Toolbox',
                })
            }
        };
    });
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let me make sure I am clear.  You want to receive a POST request, then send out multiple requests to another server, and then bundle the responses into one response to the initial POST, is that correct?

Comment: @Paul, thanks for asking and reading my question. To clarify, I just want to make several POST requests to the same server, process the response data, and display all processed data to a single res.render page. Does that make better sense?

Comment: Sort of.  So the code here is the server that will be creating this aggregate SOAP response over the course of several requests?

Comment: Indeed it is. This is actually part of an Electron app that queries a server for a bunch of information and puts it all together in a nice looking format.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the thing to remember is that there is always one request mapped to one response in HTTP.  So you can't send multiple requests and expect to get just one response from that.

Instead, you need to have the server keep track of what's been posted (perhaps in a database on a production app), and respond to each request in turn.  One way might be to respond with partial documents, or respond with other codes that indicate the submission was accepted but that you need to send another request to push more info, that sort of thing.

But again, you can't strictly accept multiple requests without responding and then respond only after all requests are given.

Comment: thanks for the reminder. I ended up editing my question to show the two separate HTTP requests being sent over. I believe that is the proper way to do it. Both requests (one labeled "HTTP.REQUEST - OPEN SESSION - CSS" and the other "HTTP.REQUEST - OPEN SESSION - PARTITIONS") return valid responses and I'm able to do data manipulation on both; I just can't figure out how to get the data from both of the requests out to that separate "res.render" statement. Does that make better sense?